# Office 365 Graph API - Files managment

Tags: api, ms-office, office365

Good day!

Trying to create new file with Office 365 Graph API:

Issue #1

Here is my request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/files?nameConflict=overwrite

Headers:
Authorization: Bearer ......
Content-Type: application/json

Body:
{"name":"Blabla.pdf","type":"File"}
```

When running this request frist time - everything is ok and file created in the root fodler. But if I will try to create this file again, I am getting response:

```
{"error":{"code":"NameAlreadyExists","message":"A resource with the same name already exists"}}
```

According to [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/files-rest-operations#FileoperationsCreateorupdateafileREST) I should send parameter through query: nameConflict=overwrite. But it does not work. I am getting error **NameAlreadyExists**.

What is the right way to overwrite existing filename?

Issue #2

How can I create new File/Folder in specified folder? Should I create new folder first and then move it to new folder [updating properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/files-rest-operations#FolderoperationsUpdatefolderpropertiesREST) ?

Answer (score 0):

**Issue #1**

The `nameConflict` query parameter does not apply to the `/files` endpoint, but actually to the `Files/{parent-id}/children/{file-name}/uploadContent` and `{base-url}/Files/getByPath('{file-path}')/uploadContent` endpoints. However, I understand the confusion in the documentation.

To update an existing file, you should use the following request with the content in the request body.

```
PUT files/root/children/Blabla.pdf/content?nameConflict=overwrite
```

**Issue #2**

Yes, you should use the update properties method to move a file/folder.

Hope this helps! Please continue to use the *office365* tag if you have more questions with the APIs.

Comment: Awesome. Please let me know how it goes and if you need any more help.